# How do I fix this solid wood bedroom door and frame?

Tags: wood, doors, bedroom

I think* I bought all the stuff I need to fix it, I just don’t know how.

Sorry I wasn’t more specific the first time, but I’m confused about how to fill in the missing wood with the wood filler compound without filling in the hole/s for the knob & latch.

Is there a right way to block those holes off? Or will I have to drill them back in?

*this based on some YouTube videos I watched.
I have all the tools, sanders, etc. I’ve always been able to figure out how to fix things myself but I’m nervous about this one.

I cannot afford to not do it on my own (I live in a city where you can’t even buy a “cheap” bar of soap for less than $4, and you have to wait for someone to come unlock the shelf case just to buy it)

I’ve been renting this apartment for over 10 years, the building is over 100 years old and that bedroom door is original. I don’t think I can get away with replacing the whole door.

[image]

Comment: How do you know you bought all the stuff needed to fix it without knowing how you were going to fix it?

Comment: That door needs extensive work, this is not a simple DIY fix. You should consider getting a new door.

Comment: Judging by the state of the door, it looks to me as though it's not the 1st time this has happened ... If you still have all the pieces you could bodge it back together with wood glue & clamps (and fit a new latch), but it'll take some amount of skill to make it look decent again (and it'll never be as strong as it was 50 years ago).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm having issues with imgur and can't see your pics, but if you [edit] your question to focus on "how do I fix this `<particular>` portion of my door", your question will likely be reopened and you'll get an answer. Then you can ask another question about fixing the next part. As it stands, this is far too broad and would take a book on woodworking to address the issue.

Comment: A 'c' battery in the strike hole? Or something. If you end up filling the knob hole then you just suck at doing **bondo**. Having to re-drill would prob crack the bondo. DO NOT overfill. And don't make it so you have to sand a bunch back off. Sanding off an 1/8" of bondo really sucks because it's a lot harder than the door and you'll just start eating into the wood around it while trying to sand. - Anything you do would be better than what it is. As long as what you bought was a trowel and a can of bondo, then thumbs up. - VTC should just be because *it's bondo time* ;)

Comment: "That door [is salvageable.] [A new door is] [...] [not a simple DIY fix]". Even I *don't* do *not* prehung doors. So that would mean pulling off the trim. And... a six hundred dollar door? Or a can of bondo at... eleven, ninety five.

Comment: You mention that you're renting, not sure of your rental contract, but this feels like a repair your landlord should be covering.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wood filler or even better, Bondo, but beware that this will be a difficult job. To avoid filling the holes, you can use something, to block the filler, for example, a toilet paper cardboard center, etc.. The problem with filling this is that this is a stress area for the door (that's how it broke in the first place, no?), so the filler might come off after a few days.

If I were fixing this in my own home, I'd cut out that area from the door, then use a piece of hardwood to replace the area cut off, then use Bondo to fill the seams. Then sand and paint. Then maybe add a metal plate, drilled to the solid parts of the door. How much DIY this solution is will depend on your skills.